# Trying to get string variables from a seperate class causing app to crash

Tags: java, android

I have simple page to start up the app that has a spinner,editText, and a button. When the user clicks the button I want the app take the selection of the spinner and text and set them to text views in the new class. I tried using getters but when I try this the app crashes.

First Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String pullerName;
String storeName;
Spinner spinner;
EditText etPuller;

public String getStoreName(){
    return storeName;
}
public String getPullerName(){
    return pullerName;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.store_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
    etPuller = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pullerName = etPuller.getText().toString();
            storeName = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Second Class:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);

    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    TextView user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
    TextView store = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStore);
    user.setText(main.getPullerName());
    store.setText(main.getStoreName());
```

When this code runs it crashes as soon as i click the button to move to the next activity.

Comment: why did you use this line of code in the MainActivity2 class `MainActivity main = new MainActivity();`

Comment: creating a instance of the MainActivity class that way I can call the methods from MainActivity.

Comment: MainActivity is already pause/stop when you open another activity..unless you open fragment.. just use bundle to pass data..

Comment: Check my answer. Use intent.putExtra() and intent.getExtras() methods to pass values between activities. Remove the code line `MainActivity main = new MainActivity();` It is useless and causes your app to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data to a new Activity you need to use Intent.

This is what you need to do:

MainActivity.class:

```
create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pullerName = etPuller.getText().toString();
            storeName = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
            i.putExtra("puller-name", pullerName);
            i.putExtra("store-name", storeName);
            startActivity(i);
        } 
    });
```

In the MainActivity2.class:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main); 

    TextView user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUser); 
    TextView store = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStore);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null){ //I always check this to avoid Exceptions
      String pullerName = intent.getStringExtra("puller-name");
      String storeName = intent.getStringExtra("store-name");

      if(pullerName != null) user.setText(pullerName);

      if(storeName != null) store.setText(storeName);
    }
}
```

You was creating a new instance of MainActivity in MainActivity2. So, when you called the getters of this mainActivity will return null, because these values were never setters. If you want to use your method, you need to pass the same instance of the activity to MainActivity2, but this is not recommended. The official method to pass data to another activity is via intent. To learn more about Intent learn the official Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong way to get values from MainActivity to MainActivity2. Simply you can pass values using the technique below.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("pullerName", pullerName);
```

To use this value pullerName in  MainActivity2 class, just use the technique below.

```
             String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pullerName");`
```

Comment: Did you remove the `MainActivity main = new MainActivity();` line ? If not, remove it

Comment: @CalebNovess did you get the answer?

Comment: I had removed that line and it is still crashing